# How do I make a constant variable next to random generated characters

Tags: python, random, concatenation

```
import random

number = random.sample(range(0,9999), 10)
print(number, file = open("output.txt","a"))
```

I want to add (prefix) characters to a randomly generated number.
e.g. `AAA(number)` so that it will become something like `AAA4525`. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: `result = f"AAA{number}"`

Comment: By the way you say "constant variable", but that's not what you actually mean, it's more appropriate to call "literal numeric value"

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
PREFIX = 'AAA'
numbers = random.sample(range(0,10000), 10) # to include also 9999
with open("output.txt","a") as f:
    for number in numbers:
        f.write(f'{PREFIX}{number:0>4d}\n')
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score -1):

Simple Concatenation can do the trick for you ..

```
def converter():
     string="AAA"
     ans= string+str(number) 
     return ans
```